# Wrong text encoding returned when query from PostgreSQL database using RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, database, postgresql, character-encoding, rpostgresql

I used R and DBI to query data from a PostgreSQL but got corrupted results with weird characters. I check both server encoding and client encoding, and they are all UTF-8. Here's what I did

1. Connect to the db

   library(DBI)

   conn <- dbConnect(
       drv = RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(),
       host = ***,
       dbname =** ,
       user = **,
       password = ***
   )
2. Fetch the result

   result_df <- dbGetQuery(
           conn,
           "select description 
           from some_table
           where user_id = 1234"
       )
3. Result
   What I got is `ã¯ã˜ã‚ã¾ã—ã¦1008(ã¨ãƒ¼ã‚„orã¨ã…ãƒ¼ã‚„)ã¨ã„ã„ã¾ã™ã€‚ è¡¨ç¾ã™ã‚‹ã®ãŒå¤§å¥½ããªå­ã§ã™!! æ„Ÿæ€§ãŒäººã¨ã‚ºãƒ¬ã¦ã¾ã™(ç¬‘) ãŠæ­Œã‚’ã‚‚ã£ã¨ã†ã¾ããªã‚ŠãŸã„ã§ã™ã€‚` 
   while the actual text is `はじめまして1008(とーやorとぅーや)といいます。 表現するのが大好きな子です!! 感性が人とズレてます(笑) お歌をもっとうまくなりたいです。`

I test again by reading the text and then print it back

```
x <- 'はじめまして1008(とーやorとぅーや)といいます。 表現するのが大好きな子です!! 感性が人とズレてます(笑) お歌をもっとうまくなりたいです。'
print(x)
>> はじめまして1008(とーやorとぅーや)といいます。 表現するのが大好きな子です!! 感性が人とズレてます(笑) お歌をもっとうまくなりたいです。
```

There's nothing wrong with the encoding in this case, so I think the problem happened when the data is returned from the database into R, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How does it look when you do the query with psql from R host machine?

Comment: it looked like this `ã¯ã˜ã‚ã¾ã—ã¦1008(ã¨ãƒ¼ã‚„orã¨ã…ãƒ¼ã‚„)ã¨ã„ã„ã¾ã™ã€‚ è¡¨ç¾ã™ã‚‹ã®ãŒå¤§å¥½ããªå­ã§ã™!! æ„Ÿæ€§ãŒäººã¨ã‚ºãƒ¬ã¦ã¾ã™(ç¬‘) ãŠæ­Œã‚’ã‚‚ã£ã¨ã†ã¾ããªã‚ŠãŸã„ã§ã™ã€`

Comment: So it does seem to have nothing to do with R. What does psql -l show and SHOW client_encoding;. Do you have any conversion going on in pg_conversion?

Comment: When I start a new databse with default en_US.utf8 and paste your text to a new table with a text column, it works and pg_dump shows your text correctly as do select. What locale do you have on your machines? They might interfere. I have sv_SE.UTF-8 on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

RPostgreSQL does not set string encodings properly, see this [issue](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/issues/52).

So in the meantime you have to declare the encoding yourself. With
dplyr, you can do it like this:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(RPostgreSQL)
})

my_con <- 
  dbConnect(
    PostgreSQL(),
    user = my_username,
    password = my_password,
    host = my_host,
    dbname = my_dbname
  )

my_table <- tribble(
  ~user_id,    ~description,
  "1234",     "はじめまして1008(とーやorとぅーや)といいます。 表現するのが大好きな子です!! 感性が人とズレてます(笑) お歌をもっとうまくなりたいです。"
)

copy_to(my_con, my_table)

result_df <- dbGetQuery(my_con, "SELECT description FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '1234'" )

declare_utf8 <- function(x) {
  Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
  x
}

result_df %>% mutate_if(is.character, declare_utf8) %>% pull()
#> [1] "はじめまして1008(とーやorとぅーや)といいます。 表現するのが大好きな子です!! 感性が人とズレてます(笑) お歌をもっとうまくなりたいです。"

dbDisconnect(my_con)
#> [1] TRUE
```

`pull()` is not necessary here. I just use it because your `description`
would not print right as a `data.frame()` on my machine due to
another [character encoding
bug](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/%7Eizahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/),
so I am `pull`ing it out as a vector.